# How can a Java code could being used in a Jquery keeping it in a same form

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have made a code in Java but wanted to use it in Jquery because my whole project works on jquery now how can I use this code in Jquery making sure that it fuctionality to take random number from an array doesn't changes.My code is as follows :-

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ARRAan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cards[]={1,2,3,6,1,25,24,2,62,85,65,};
        int temp1;
        int temp;
        Random randIndex = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <cards.length; i++)
        {
            temp1 = randIndex.nextInt(i+2);
            temp = cards[i];
            cards[i] = cards[temp1];
            cards[temp1] = temp;
            System.out.println(  cards[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

Now where I wanted to use this program in Jquery is-

```
function shuffle() {
 return 0.5 - Math.random();
  }
```

Comment: Rewrite it in Javascript.

Comment: Is this a joke or something...

Comment: You made wrong choice of technologies. Anyway, if your backend is in JAVA use AJAX to send requests from jquery to your jsp or something.

Comment: You are generating random card in your Java Code. I'm not familiar with java or jsp but there should be a way to handle http requests. So when you send a http request to your jsp, it will send the card back to jquery. From there, you can continue.

Comment: Better you take others' advice and switch to javascript. Unless you want to hide the way you are generating random card. JavaScript code is open to world.

Comment: @nightgaunt ok fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what you've asked:

> I have made a code in Java but wanted to use it in Jquery [sic]

That's the answer to your question. If you've written it in Java, you'll have to rewrite it in JavaScript if you want to use it with your jQuery-based project.

That really shouldn't be too hard, as the syntax is similar.

All you need to rewrite is your `main` (the rest is irrelevant in JS):

```js
var cards = [1,2,3,6,1,25,24,2,62,85,65];
var temp1;
var temp;
var randIndex = Math.random();

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    temp1 = randIndex.nextInt(i+2);
    temp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[temp1];
    cards[temp1] = temp;
    console.log(cards[i]);
}
```

Replace `int` with `var`, change your array syntax, and replace your `Random` object with a `Math.random()` call.

Nothing too tricky here.

Comment: There is no language called jQuery...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Very true: fixed.

Comment: @aspirant Any reason for unaccepting? Did your requirements change?

Comment: @AstroCB Since it has been negatively voted thats why I am not doing so :(

Comment: @aspirant See [Why is voting important?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Votes should encourage you to edit the question and fix it up, not to unaccept answers. If my answer solved your question, you should accept it for future reference of others.

Comment: @aspirant Thanks. I'd recommend reading through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) if you want to fix up this post or prevent your future posts from being closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cards=[1,2,3,6,1,25,24,2,62,85,65];
var temp1;
var temp;
var randIndex = Math.random();

for (var i = 0; i <cards.length; i++)
{
    temp1 = randIndex.nextInt(i+2);
    temp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[temp1];
    cards[temp1] = temp;
    console.log(  cards[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run java code in jquery, jquery is a library for javascript and java is a programming language. also jquery is more for UI, animation and other web related things, your code seems to be logic code.